# Laptop won't suspend Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: suspend, 14.04

Toshiba Satellite L855D with fresh 14.04 LTS install, will not suspend, screen goes dark for 2 seconds, then shows the lock screen.

Another post suggested trying:

```
sudo modprobe toshiba_acpi
```

but this has not made a difference.

My computer is an AMD A8-4500M APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics × 4 Gallium 0.4 on AMD ARUBA.

Any ideas?

Comment: You're possibly seeing this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xfce4-power-manager/+bug/1303736 . Try removing 'light-locker' and 'light-locker-settings' and installing 'xscreensaver' to solve the issue of buggy suspend/resume.

Comment: I disagree this is off-topic.  I'm having the same problem.  I don't find it substantially any different than "I'm having trouble with my apache.conf" or "can someone explain how to find the Ubuntu version I'm running"; those questions are not closed as "off topic".  Would it have made a difference if the OP phrased the question as "how to I make Ubuntu 14.04 suspend?  When I select the menu, it doesn't." ?  I also find this post similar to http://askubuntu.com/questions/763085/with-ubuntu-16-04-laptop-doesnt-suspend-when-lid-is-closed, but it has not  been closed as "off topic".

Answer (score 0):

Try this

http://johny65corp.blogspot.mx/2011/11/arreglar-suspenderhibernar-en-ubuntu.html

That works for me, try it

This is a more direct link to the fix:
http://thecodecentral.com/2011/01/18/fix-ubuntu-10-10-suspendhibernate-not-working-bug

Comment: Please include the essential steps from this link into your answer.\