# How to get laptop lid to suspend & resume, and wifi to reconnect with Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: suspend, laptop, 16.04

On my Compaq Presario CQ62 laptop Ubuntu 14.04 would suspend on lid close.  But a clean install of 16.04 ignored the lid action.  According to [with-ubuntu-16-04-laptop-doesnt-suspend-when-lid-is-closed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/763085/with-ubuntu-16-04-laptop-doesnt-suspend-when-lid-is-closed) (which I can't post on) there's a kernel bug fixed in version 4.4.8 whereas 16.04 has just shipped with 4.4.0. Everything else works so I decided to try to fix it with the existing kernel. Following instructions on [laptop-does-not-suspend-when-lid-is-closed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/395428/laptop-does-not-suspend-when-lid-is-closed) was helpful but outdated and caused wifi to fail to reconnect on resume. What's the best way to cause a lid close event to enter suspend mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get ACPI to perform suspend create /etc/acpi/events/lidbtn and /etc/acpi/lidbtn.sh as below.

```
sudo sh

cat <<. >/etc/acpi/lidbtn.sh
#!/bin/sh
# Initiate suspend mode when the lid has been closed.

# Only act on a lid close event
if grep -q open /proc/acpi/button/lid/LID0/state
then
    dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.login1 /org/freedesktop/login1 "org.freedesktop.login1.Manager.Suspend" boolean:true
fi
.

cat <<. >/etc/acpi/events/lidbtn
# Laptop lid event triggered.  Call /etc/acpi/lidbtn.sh

event=button[ /]lid
action=/etc/acpi/lidbtn.sh
.

exit
```

I also tried `/usr/sbin/pm-suspend` and `sudo /lib/systemd/systemd-sleep suspend` as alternatives to the `dbus-send` line, but these resulted in wifi not authenticating reliably after resume.  I found `/etc/default/acpi-support` to be helpful background reading, stating that `acpi-support` is deprecated and dbus-pm, dbus-hal, or pm-utils are the current methods.

Other reference links: [power-closelid](https://help.ubuntu.com/16.04/ubuntu-help/power-closelid.html), [running-script-before-suspending-while-using-dbus](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/175152/running-script-before-suspending-while-using-dbus), [UPower](https://upower.freedesktop.org/docs/UPower.html)