# Xubuntu 16.04.1 won't wake up correctly after opening lid

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, suspend, laptop, power-management

Recently, I install Xubuntu 16.04 on my Acer Aspire E1-570G. It wasn't going to suspend when I close the lid, so I used a little trick by uncommenting `HandleLidSwitchDocked=suspend` on `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` and it worked properly (when opening and closing lid, everything was OK).

Yesterday, I upgraded my Xubuntu to 16.04.1 by using `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`.

My devices suspends when I close its lid, but when I open it back, I just see a command line cursor blinking and after a few seconds it stops blinking and nothing more comes out, have to restart it by `ALT+PRT SC` and type `REISUB`.

What should I do to fix this problem?

P.S.: sorry for too much details :)

Comment: I tried the kernel update, didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try upgrading your kernel. Seemed to do the trick for me.

Second answer here: [With Ubuntu 16.04 laptop doesn't suspend when lid is closed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/763085/with-ubuntu-16-04-laptop-doesnt-suspend-when-lid-is-closed)

Comment: I just started upgrading my kernel from 4.4.8 to 4.8.1 . About the second answer, I followed the instructions there and that's my problem now (read my question again).

Comment: Wasn't all that awake when I posted that.  Updating the kernel was the second answer in that post, which is why I suggested it. Thought you had already updated it and I just read it wrong, which is why I deleted the answer. Glad you've figured it out in spite of my grogginess.