# Suspend on lid close doesn't work 16.04

Tags: 16.04, suspend, laptop, asus, lid

I've checked each and every option and possible solutions but my ASUS laptop doesn't suspend when I close the lid. All settings were set proper via the menues but nothing happens. When I perform a suspend from ubuntu menu it works perfect. Ok, I had to add a "network-manager restart" because of disabled Wifi but in the end suspend and resume in general works.

I have tested the scripts from the other posts and in addition uncommented the "HandleLidSwitch(Docked)" events to suspend but it didn't help. Tried everything below [With Ubuntu 16.04 laptop doesn't suspend when lid is closed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/763085/with-ubuntu-16-04-laptop-doesnt-suspend-when-lid-is-closed) but nothing worked for me.

I was able to check with external monitor that the lid switch in general works. I checked /proc/acpi/button/lid/LID/state and found "closed" or "opened" correctly.

In log of journalctl I can see that systemd-logind is "watching system buttons for LID"

Here is the relevant text:

```
Okt 21 15:35:28 Dijana-ASUS systemd-logind[643]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event0 (Lid Switch)
```

A different laptop with same 16.04 LTS shows the same entry in journalctl but there suspend on lid works and the lid close event is recognized by systemd-logind.

Is this a bug or is my laptop simply too stupid? On a different partition I have tested the old 14.04.5 (with latest kernel) and I have the same misbehaviour...

Can anyone help?

Regards, Dijana

Additional information...
ASUS F453S with Intel® Celeron(R) CPU N3050 @ 1.60GHz × 2

Ubuntu shows Intel® HD Graphics (Cherryview)

lspci | grep VGA shows 
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 22b1 (rev 21)

Comment: Please edit and add the exact model and also hardware specs. It may be related with graphics drivers or others.

Comment: To circumvent the same problem I wrote a script to intercept lid close. Then later I upgraded Kernel and stopped using script.

Comment: Updated technical information... @WinEunuuch2Unix: Do you have more info about this script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in the end I gave up and did it via workaround script.
Just created a script like this and put it to root crontab for executing every 5 minutes.
Not nice but it works and in the end it's only for those cases that our child closes the lid.
Here is the content of the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
if grep -q closed /proc/acpi/button/lid/*/state

then
     /usr/sbin/pm-suspend
 fi
```

Comment: You can mark your own answer as accepted by clicking the gray check mark beside the answer to change its color to green.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed with using acpid with the following solution

```
sudo gedit /etc/acpi/events/lidclose
```

copy, paste & save

```
event=button[ /]lid
action=/etc/acpi/lidclose.sh
```

execute

```
sudo gedit /etc/acpi/lidclose.sh
```

copy, paste & save

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "close" > /home/jesse/close.txt
if grep -q closed /proc/acpi/button/lid/*/state

then
     /usr/sbin/pm-suspend
fi
```

execute

```
sudo chmod ugo+x /etc/acpi/lidclose.sh
```

restart acpi service or reboot

Comment: Didn't work for me (Asus N550JV).

Comment: Don't forget to install pm-utils first.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to the [4.9-rc1 kernel](https://lkml.org/lkml/2016/10/15/112) fixed the problem on my Asus. Different model (X540SA) but had the same issue. The change-log contained several ACPI and power management fixes.

> - power management updates
> - ACPI updates
> - PNP update
> - more power management updates
> - more ACPI updates

[4.9-rc2](https://lkml.org/lkml/2016/10/23/203) was just released with similar changes but I can not confirm that it also resolved the issue.

Also, have you checked your BIOS settings for waking on lid opening? Hate to ask but I know some AMI BIOS versions can be confusing.

Comment: I will try the newest kernel. Tried one 4.6.-Kernel and I got after a couple of minutes always GPU problems. Unity was completely frozen so I switched back to kernel 4.4.21

Comment: BIOS setting I didn't check but when I manually suspend and close the lid then my laptop resumes when opening lid again.

Comment: The 4.6-4.8 kernels either didn't fix the issue or made GPU issues even worse for me too. I was really surprised to find that 4.9 changed everything. Also, sounds like BIOS settings are not the culprit. @DijanaMarkovic

Comment: Tried kernel 4.9-RC1 and system hung up after showing terminal messages regarding "probably missing firmware i915"... I had to remove this kernel so problem still open.  BIOS setting is proper.

Comment: I did a reinstall of Linux Mint on another partition and received the same message. Have you opened driver settings and enabled the intel microcode proprietary drivers for your machine? I enabled them and then attempted to reinstall 4.9 and it worked perfectly. Did not spit "probably missing..." error @DijanaMarkovic