# Laptop will not suspend on lid close

Tags: suspend, laptop, xps

I am having an issue where closing the lid on my laptop will not suspend.

## System

- Dell XPS 15 7590
- Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
- i3 version 4.17.1 (2019-08-30)

## Steps taken to fix

### Check suspending manually work

Both `sudo pm-suspend` and `sudo systemctl suspend` work just fine. I can suspend and resume by running them directly.

### Ensure logind config is correct

`~ cat /etc/systemd/logind.conf`

```
HandleLidSwitch=suspend
HandleLidSwitchExternalPower=suspend
HandleLidSwitchDocked=suspend
#LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited=yes
```

### Check lid switch is not disabled

`~ grep -i lid /etc/UPower/UPower.conf`

```
# Do we ignore the lid state
# Some laptops are broken. The lid state is either inverted, or stuck
IgnoreLid=false
```

### Check lid closing is detected

`~ journalctl | grep -i " lid "`

```
Aug 20 09:27:54 nuitari kernel: input: Lid Switch as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0D:00/input/input0
Aug 20 09:27:54 nuitari kernel: ACPI: Lid Switch [LID0]
Aug 20 09:27:57 nuitari /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1216]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device Lid Switch (/dev/input/event0)
Aug 20 09:28:07 nuitari /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2212]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device Lid Switch (/dev/input/event0)
Aug 20 09:28:19 nuitari systemd-logind[1004]: Lid closed.
Aug 20 09:28:19 nuitari kernel: ACPI: button: The lid device is not compliant to SW_LID.
Aug 20 09:28:37 nuitari systemd-logind[1004]: Lid opened.
Aug 20 09:41:14 nuitari systemd-logind[1004]: Lid closed.
Aug 20 09:41:27 nuitari systemd-logind[1004]: Lid opened.
Aug 20 09:41:36 nuitari systemd-logind[1004]: Lid closed.
Aug 20 09:41:42 nuitari systemd-logind[1004]: Lid opened.
```

### Other askubuntu solutions

I am tempted to try something like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/840093/suspend-on-lid-close-doesnt-work-16-04) to get it working, but that feels more like a hacky workaround than a proper solution.

I would appreciate any help diagnosing this.