# Laptop not suspending after closing my lid

Tags: nvidia, suspend, power-management, laptop, 20.10

I am using Asus Vivobook 15 X510U with Intel i7 - 8550U, 8 GB RAM, Nvidia MX 150.
After a recent update, my laptop is failing to suspend when the lid closes. When I open the lid again, it shows only the Asus logo and I have to hard reboot the system again

POP!_OS : 20.10
Kernel : 5.11.0-7614-generic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try looking on power management in the system settings. There should be a section where it says `when laptop lid closed...` and then you have the various options.
Have you tried this [Suspend on lid close doesn't work 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/840093/suspend-on-lid-close-doesnt-work-16-04?rq=1) ?

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot. That script solved the issue! Thanks a lot again:)

Comment: Hi, the solution you gave worked. But after suspending for 30 mins, my laptop wakes up with a blank screen. Do you have any fix for that? @enrico223

Comment: Unfortunately I don't, sorry...

Comment: Don't be sorry! I found out about the black screen issue. It turns out to be NVIDIA driver issue. I reinstalled and it's now fine. Thanks for your reply. :)